# Edit Particle size missing?

Tags: particles

I'm sure I'm just be being a n00b here, but the size value for my particle systems seems to be missing. It should be right there next to mass under physics, right? [image]

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please take screenshots instead of photos https://www.take-a-screenshot.org. Particle size is no longer there rather in the Render rollout instead

Comment: Taking screenshots in blender is quite easy. Press Ctrl+F3 and save the image. You can choose to save just the active window or the whole interface.